# How do I do simple Many To Many in EF 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have a simple enough set of tables in a typical many to many relationship.

TableA => TableAB <= TableB

The TableAB has a compound PK which contains TableAID and TableBID.

I want to get a list of all the TableB's given a TableAID The sql would look like:

```
select *
from tableA A
inner join TableAB AB
on A.AID = AB.AID
inner join TableB B
on AB.BID = B.ID
where A.ID = 5
```

I know this seems pretty basic but I am trying to get it to work for hours now with entity framework 5 and MVC 4 lambdas.

My code looks like this so far (its mostly wrong):

```
Entities db = new Entities()

public List<TableB> GetBData(int AID)
{
    var tableAdata = db.TableA.Where(a => a.AID == AID)

    List<TableAB> tableB = new List<TableB>();
    foreach (var a in tableAData)
         tableB.BID = db.TableB.BID
}
```

I was thinking there must be a way to pass the ID of table A into this, then link that table with the link table and return all the BID's that exist there, then use the BID's returned (0 to many) to get the data from the B table.

I taught this might be possible by daisy chaining multiple where clauses but I am not sure how to do it so I am asking for guidance.

Just to clarify...I setup this model in SQL Server 2012 first (so not using code first), then put EF5 in my MVC4 project. So EF5 has done it's thing with regard to coding the models. I have not altered or added to anything that EF5 has done with its models. But I am open to making any alterations that should be needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easier would be to simply use the LINQ syntax:

```
var result = from a in db.TableA
             join ab in db.TableAB on a.AID equals ab.AID
             join b in db.TableB on ab.BID equals b.BID
             where a.AID == 5
             select b;
```

Of course you could write that using the static Enumerable extension methods - in fact that's what the compiler does - but it is harder since you have to create some objects just to store the results of each join operation. So I'd just let the compiler do that for you.

Comment: Anything that gets me the result...I can alter it after the deadlines are passed. I'll give your result a try now and be back to accept it if works. Cheers.